# Call to undefined relationship [categories] on model [App\Category]

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

hello m trying to get categories/products seprately, like when i click on specific category then its related products shown:

but it says: Call to undefined relationship [categories] on model [App\Category].

actually my categories starts from "8" when i type 8 to replace 0 then it shows : Undefined variable: categoriesDetails

```
  categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent_id'=>0])->get();
```

code of ProductsController:

```
  public function products($url = null){

  $categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent_id'=>0])->get();

  $categoryDetails = Category::where(['url' => $url])->first();
  $productsAll = Product::where(['category_id' => $categoriesDetails->id])->get();
  return view('products.listing')->with(compact('categories','categoryDetails','productsAll'));
}
```

code of Product model:

```
  <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
 public function category(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');

 }
}
```

Comment: You're defining the relationship as `category()`, so you can't call `categories`...

Comment: i changed it to $categoriesDet = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent_id'=>0])->get();return view('products.listing')->with(compact('categoriesDet','categoryDetails','productsAll')); but still same error

Comment: `public function category()` should be `public function categories()` to work via `->with("categories")`. You function name needs to be the same as what you're using in `->with()`. Currently, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Your `with` must match the function's name. `with('category')` will work, but you should probably rename it to `categories` if a product can have multiple categories.

Comment: changed it to category but same result

Comment: @azibdhaken You have other issues in this code, yes. `Category::with('categories')` doesn't make sense - categories don't have categories, your products do. You'd do something like `Product::with('categories')`, or `Category::with('products')`. I strongly recommend you go re-read the docs on Eloquent relationships and how they work.

Comment: nice now its showing "Undefined variable: categoriesDetails" at this line:$productsAll = Product::where(['category_id' => $categoriesDetails->id])->get();

Comment: would u prefer to tell me this last sol.